# python newbie range not working

Tags: python, range

I'm doing some homework and I dont understand why my `range(1,13)`:
is not updating Minimum monthly payment 168.52 Remaining Balance 4111.89
but it does update the month... I want those two things to updates as the months go by, from month 1 - 12, they just wont update for me.

```
balance = 4213
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04
month = 0
Total_amount_paid = 0
for month in range(1,13):
    print('Month'), month
    minimumpayment =  balance * monthlyPaymentRate
    print('Minimum monthly payment'), ('%.2f' % minimumpayment)
    Monthly_interest_rate =  (annualInterestRate/12) 
    Monthly_unpaid_balance = balance - minimumpayment
    Updated_balance_each_month = Monthly_unpaid_balance * \
    (annualInterestRate / 12.0) + Monthly_unpaid_balance
    print('Remaining Balance'), ('%.2f' % Updated_balance_each_month)
    Total_amount_paid = Total_amount_paid + minimumpayment
    print 'Total paid', ('%.2f' % Total_amount_paid)
    print 'Remaining balance', ('%.2f' % Updated_balance_each_month)
```

Comment: You always calculate `minimumpayment` as `balance * monthlyPaymentRate`. Why would you expect it to change?

Comment: `minimumpayment` is calculated using `monthlyPaymentRate` and `balance`.  Neither of those variables change inside the for loop.

Comment: I'm not clear what is not updating.  Are you saying you only need the remaining balance to update?

Comment: You never change the balance.  You changed the updated balance, but you are using *balance* in your calculation.

Comment: You should wait until the MITx pset is over and get help there, getting people to do your homework not only defeats the purpose but is also against the honor code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `balance` to:    `Updated_balance_each_month` You're never changing the variable `balance` which stays at 4213 for the entire program, as it is defined outside the `for` loop.

```
# the results do not update after each month ='( 

Updated_balance_each_month = 4213
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04
month = 0
Total_amount_paid = 0
for month in range(1,13):
    print('Month'), month
    minimumpayment =  Updated_balance_each_month * monthlyPaymentRate
    print('Minimum monthly payment'), ('%.2f' % minimumpayment)
    Monthly_interest_rate =  (annualInterestRate/12) 
    Monthly_unpaid_balance = Updated_balance_each_month - minimumpayment
    Updated_balance_each_month = Monthly_unpaid_balance * \
    (annualInterestRate / 12.0) + Monthly_unpaid_balance
    print('Remaining Balance'), ('%.2f' % Updated_balance_each_month)
    Total_amount_paid = Total_amount_paid + minimumpayment
print 'Total paid', ('%.2f' % Total_amount_paid)
print 'Remaining balance', ('%.2f' % Updated_balance_each_month)

Month 1
Minimum monthly payment 168.52
Remaining Balance 4111.89
Month 2
Minimum monthly payment 164.48
Remaining Balance 4013.20
Month 3
Minimum monthly payment 160.53
Remaining Balance 3916.89
Month 4
Minimum monthly payment 156.68
Remaining Balance 3822.88
Month 5
Minimum monthly payment 152.92
Remaining Balance 3731.13
Month 6
Minimum monthly payment 149.25
Remaining Balance 3641.58
Month 7
Minimum monthly payment 145.66
Remaining Balance 3554.19
Month 8
Minimum monthly payment 142.17
Remaining Balance 3468.89
Month 9
Minimum monthly payment 138.76
Remaining Balance 3385.63
Month 10
Minimum monthly payment 135.43
Remaining Balance 3304.38
Month 11
Minimum monthly payment 132.18
Remaining Balance 3225.07
Month 12
Minimum monthly payment 129.00
Remaining Balance 3147.67
Total paid 1775.55
Remaining balance 3147.67
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll vote you up if I had the reputation :)  but Im new here :) the error was me not the range lol see what I missed !

Comment: You're welcome.  Get some rep. :)  Contribute to others.

Comment: thanks so much !!! I'm new here this website is amazing ! thanks johnny, I will ! :)